# simple python algorithm needed in finding bounding box of meshes from an OBJ file

Tags: python, .obj

I'm trying a packing problem using Python and OBJ files. I'm a novice in python and not sure how to manipulate the OBJ file vertices to find the optimal bounding box. Any sample python code to get me started? Here's a simple box OBJ file to start with which I'll need to fit into a larger container. In short, can object X fit into object Y. Then ultimately how many x can fit into Y with the most optimal solution, but that's for way later.

Here's the .OBJ files for the small and bigger boxes
Small:

```
# Rhino
```

v -5 -5 0
v -5 -5 5
v 0 -5 0
v 0 -5 5
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 4/4/4 2/2/2 1/1/1 3/3/3
v 0 -5 0
v 0 -5 5
v 0 0 0
v 0 0 5
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
f 8/8/8 6/6/6 5/5/5 7/7/7
v 0 0 0
v 0 0 5
v -5 0 0
v -5 0 5
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
f 12/12/12 10/10/10 9/9/9 11/11/11
v -5 0 0
v -5 0 5
v -5 -5 0
v -5 -5 5
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn -1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
vn -1 0 0
f 16/16/16 14/14/14 13/13/13 15/15/15
v -5 -5 0
v 0 -5 0
v -5 0 0
v 0 0 0
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 0 -1
f 20/20/20 18/18/18 17/17/17 19/19/19
v -5 -5 5
v -5 0 5
v 0 -5 5
v 0 0 5
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
f 24/24/24 22/22/22 21/21/21 23/23/23

Bigger box:

```
# Rhino
```

v 0 0 0
v 0 0 20
v 0 20 0
v 0 20 20
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn -1 -0 -0
vn -1 -0 -0
vn -1 -0 -0
vn -1 -0 -0
f 4/4/4 3/3/3 1/1/1 2/2/2
v 0 20 0
v 0 20 20
v 20 20 0
v 20 20 20
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 1 0
f 8/8/8 7/7/7 5/5/5 6/6/6
v 20 20 0
v 20 20 20
v 20 0 0
v 20 0 20
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
f 12/12/12 11/11/11 9/9/9 10/10/10
v 20 0 0
v 20 0 20
v 0 0 0
v 0 0 20
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 16/16/16 15/15/15 13/13/13 14/14/14
v 0 0 0
v 0 20 0
v 20 0 0
v 20 20 0
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn -0 -0 -1
vn -0 -0 -1
vn -0 -0 -1
vn -0 -0 -1
f 20/20/20 19/19/19 17/17/17 18/18/18
v 0 0 20
v 20 0 20
v 0 20 20
v 20 20 20
vt 0 0
vt 0 1
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 1
f 24/24/24 23/23/23 21/21/21 22/22/22

```
enter code here
```

Comment: your question isn't clear at all. If you want to compute a bounding box of an object just take the min and max x, y, z value of each vertex. What does that have to do with fitting different models?

Comment: don't i need to find the bounding box first to see if one fits into another?

Comment: Fit in what sense? That one bounding box is larger than another? Or that one object could be completely 'within' the mesh of the other (very hard problem to solve)? Or do you mean something else by 'fitting' ?

Comment: i c, eventually i need to see if one is completely within the other. But right now just calculating the bounding boxes and comparing the bounding boxes for volume size is what I need to get me started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to answer the question in your title:

- Load each object file as a list of vertices, I assume you already hsve some code to load .obj files in python (if not, you could adjust this [loadObj()](http://www.nandnor.net/?p=86) function for example, make it return the verts variable)
- for each object, compute the bounding box, e.g.:

---

```
def verts_to_bbox(verts):
    xs = [v[0] for v in verts]
    ys = [v[1] for v in verts]
    zs = [v[2] for v in verts]
    return (min(xs), max(xs), min(ys), max(ys), min(zs), max(zs))
```

---

Now on to testing if one object 'fits' in the other. Basically, you want to know if one bounding box is equal or smaller than the other in all dimensions, as I understand you.
So,

- Compute for each bounding box its size in x, y and z dimension, e.g.:

---

```
def bbox_size(bbox):
    # return tuple with sizes (dx, dy, dz)
    return (bbox[1] - bbox[0], bbox[3] - bbox[2], bbox[5] - bbox[4])

def fits_bbox(bigbox, smallbox):
    bdx, bdy, bdz = bbox_size(bigbox)
    sdx, sdy, sdz = bbox_size(smallbox)
    # return True if small box fits in bigbox in all three dimensions
    return (sdx<bdx and sdy<bdy and sdz<bdz)
```

---

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to iterate over the obj data looking for 'v's and checking if the following x y and z coordinates and recording the highest and lowest value each time you encounter it. The following code prints out the highest and lowest value for each dimension and then gives you the bounding box from that

```
obj = 'v -5 -5 0 v -5 -5 5 v 0 -5 0 v 0 -5 5 vt 0 0 vt 0 1 vt 1 0 vt 1 1 vn 0 -1 0 vn 0 -1 0 vn 0 -1 0 vn 0 -1 0 f 4/4/4 2/2/2 1/1/1 3/3/3 v 0 -5 0 v 0 -5 5 v 0 0 0 v 0 0 5 vt 0 0 vt 0 1 vt 1 0 vt 1 1 vn 1 0 0 vn 1 0 0 vn 1 0 0 vn 1 0 0 f 8/8/8 6/6/6 5/5/5 7/7/7 v 0 0 0 v 0 0 5 v -5 0 0 v -5 0 5 vt 0 0 vt 0 1 vt 1 0 vt 1 1 vn 0 1 0 vn 0 1 0 vn 0 1 0 vn 0 1 0 f 12/12/12 10/10/10 9/9/9 11/11/11 v -5 0 0 v -5 0 5 v -5 -5 0 v -5 -5 5 vt 0 0 vt 0 1 vt 1 0 vt 1 1 vn -1 0 0 vn -1 0 0 vn -1 0 0 vn -1 0 0 f 16/16/16 14/14/14 13/13/13 15/15/15 v -5 -5 0 v 0 -5 0 v -5 0 0 v 0 0 0 vt 0 0 vt 0 1 vt 1 0 vt 1 1 vn 0 0 -1 vn 0 0 -1 vn 0 0 -1 vn 0 0 -1 f 20/20/20 18/18/18 17/17/17 19/19/19 v -5 -5 5 v -5 0 5 v 0 -5 5 v 0 0 5 vt 0 0 vt 0 1 vt 1 0 vt 1 1 vn 0 0 1 vn 0 0 1 vn 0 0 1 vn 0 0 1 f 24/24/24 22/22/22 21/21/21 23/23/23'

elements = obj.split(' ')

x_min = 0.0
x_max = 0.0
y_min = 0.0
y_max = 0.0
z_min = 0.0
z_max = 0.0

i = 0

while i < len(elements):
    if elements[i] == 'v':
        #find min and max x value
        if float(elements[i + 1]) < x_min:
            x_min = float(elements[i + 1])
        elif float(elements[i + 1]) > x_max:
            x_max = float(elements[i + 1])

        #find min and max y value
        if float(elements[i + 2]) < y_min:
            y_min = float(elements[i + 2])
        elif float(elements[i + 2]) > y_max:
            y_max = float(elements[i + 2])

        #find min and max x value
        if float(elements[i + 3]) < z_min:
            z_min = float(elements[i + 3])
        elif float(elements[i + 3]) > z_max:
            z_max = float(elements[i + 3]) 

        #incriment the counter int by 4 as we know the next 4 elements are not a vertex
        i += 4

    else:
        i += 1

print 'x_min = ' + str(x_min)
print 'x_max = ' + str(x_max)   
print 'y_min = ' + str(y_min)
print 'y_max = ' + str(y_max)
print 'z_min = ' + str(z_min)
print 'z_max = ' + str(z_max)
print ''
print 'x_widh = ' + (str(x_max - x_min))
print 'y_widh = ' + (str(y_max - y_min))
print 'z_widh = ' + (str(z_max - z_min))
```

And heres the output i get

```
x_min = -5.0
x_max = 0.0
y_min = -5.0
y_max = 0.0
z_min = 0.0
z_max = 5.0

x_widh = 5.0
y_widh = 5.0
z_widh = 5.0
```

Hope that makes sense